# Kong Enterprise Installation on Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, kong, mashape

I've followed the instructions given in this [link](https://github.com/Kong/kong-dist-kubernetes) to setup kong on kubernetes container in my local machine. I'm able to access APIs behind kong through Kubernetes (minikube) IP. Now, I've enterprise edition (trial version) of kong. Without Kubernetes, i've downloaded Kong enterprise image and able to run Kong in my local machine. But, my question is how to setup enterprise Kong installation on kubernetes container. I assume that i've to tweak "image section" in .yaml to pull enterprise Kong image. But i'm not sure how to do that. Can you help us how to go ahead with enterprise Kong installation on Kubernetes container?

Answer (score 0):

There are (at least) two answers to your question:

1. set up a private docker registry -- even one inside your own kubernetes cluster -- and push the image to it, then point the `image:` at the internal registry

   that assumes that your enterprise purchase didn't come with access to an authenticated registry hosted by Mashape, would would absolutely be the preferred mechanism for that problem
2. or *I think* you can pre-load the docker image onto the nodes via [PodSpec:initContainers:](https://kubernetes.io/docs/api-reference/v1.8/#podspec-v1-core) in any number of ways: ftp, http, s3api, nfs, ... because the initContainer will run before the Pod container, I would expect `kubelet` will delay the image pull of the container until the initContainer has finished. If I had a working cluster in front of me, I'd try it out, so take this one with a grain of salt

Comment: Thank you Matthew! I hope it helps.